# How do i display this data in laravel blade ? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

The index function calls all other functions from the same class.
I am trying to load data from all the functions into the index function which will return the view along with the `$homePage` array.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->getSlider();
    $this->getHeaderCategory();
    $this->getTrendingProducts();
    $this->getBodyCategory();
    return $this->homePage;
}
```

This is the response.

```
   {
        "Sliders": [
            [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "adminId": 3,
                    "title": "Slider 3",
                    "content": "Content 3",
                    "buttonContent": "S3 C3",
                    "redirection": "none",
                    "productId": 3,
                    "categoryId": 3,
                    "sliderNumber": 1,
                    "image": null,
                    "imagePath": null,
                    "status": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-07-19 07:06:09",
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "adminId": 2,
                    "title": "Slider 2",
                    "content": "Content 2",
                    "buttonContent": "S2 C2",
                    "redirection": "none",
                    "productId": 2,
                    "categoryId": 2,
                    "sliderNumber": 2,
                    "image": null,
                    "imagePath": null,
                    "status": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-07-15 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ],

        ],
    }
```

Comment: Try 
`public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data[] = $this->getSlider();
        $data[] = $this->getHeaderCategory();
        $data[] = $this->getTrendingProducts();
        $data[] = $this->getBodyCategory();
        return view('home', compact('data'));
    }`

Comment: How do i display data in laravel blade. The **$data** would be a combination of collection and array within eachother. How do i iterate it in the blade ? @DhananjayKyada

Comment: Use `public function index() { 
    $data = []; 
    $data['slider_data'] = $this->getSlider(); 
    $data['header_category'] = $this->getHeaderCategory(); 
    $data['trending_products'] = $this->getTrendingProducts(); 
    $data['body_category'] = $this->getBodyCategory(); 
    return view('home', compact('data'));
 }` instead and you can use like `data.slider_data` in `blade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public function index() { 
    $data = []; 
    $data['slider_data'] = $this->getSlider(); 
    $data['header_category'] = $this->getHeaderCategory(); 
    $data['trending_products'] = $this->getTrendingProducts(); 
    $data['body_category'] = $this->getBodyCategory(); 
    return view('home', compact('data')); 
}
```

instead and you can use like `{{data.slider_data}}` in your `blade` file

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data into a variable called `$data['yourVariableName']` (as how Dhananjay has suggested in the comments), you will be able to access it in your view as `$yourVariableName`. Link to documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#creating-views

```
public function index()
{
        $data['slider'] = $this->getSlider();
        $data['headerCategory'] = $this->getHeaderCategory();
        ...
        return view('your.view', $data);
}
```

Then in your blade:

`{{ $slider }}`

Comment: @Soumil_13 nice one! Feel free to mark as correct if it all worked out for you.